# Set Map.Entry value AFTER iteration complete?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

Can I save Map.Entry objects in a temporary Map and then go back and change their values AFTER iteration has completed?

For example, the following implements a sort of transaction in two steps. In step 1, a map of entries and maps of entries (so a tree of sorts) is recursively processed. Entries are processed into new values which are saved to a temporary map, keyed by the corresponding Map.Entry. If all entries are computed without Exception, step 2 is to simply iterate over the temporary map and assign the corresponding new value.

```
void performPerilousProcedure(Object val) throws Exception
{
    if (processing of val fails)
        throw new Exception();
}
void recurivePerilousProcedure(Map someMap, Map tmp) throws Exception
{
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Object>> iter1;
    iter1 = someMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iter1.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String,Object> entry1 = iter1.next();
        Object val = entry1.getValue();
        if (val instanceof Map) {
            recursivePerilousProcedure((Map)val, tmp);
        } else {
            Object newval = performPerilousProcedure(val);
            // ok to use Map.Entry as key across iter?
            tmp.put(entry1, newval);
        }   
    }   
}
void doit(Map<String,Object> someMap) throws Exception
{
    HashMap<Map.Entry<String,Object>,Object> tmp = new HashMap();
    // Try to process map of entries and maps of entries and ma ... 
    recursivePerilousProcedure(someMap, tmp);
    // All entries success processed, now simply assign new vals
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String,Object>> iter2;
    iter2 = tmp.keySet().iterator();
    while (iter2.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String,Object> entry2 = iter2.next();
        Object newval = tmp.get(entry2);
        entry2.setValue(newval); // commit new value
    }   
}
```

The question is:

Can the `Map.Entry` objects used as keys of `tmp` survive outside the iterations?

Provided that there are no concurrent modifications, is this a valid use of the Map interface?

Comment: What do you mean with “all values”? Your `if` statements process exactly one value. Is there any reason for not using an idiomatic loop?

Comment: No because, `somemap` is actually a tree of maps so I need to traverse and process each element and then, only if all values of entries have been processed successfully, I then iterate over `tmp` and commit the `newval`. So my question is: do `Map.Entry` objects acquired during iteration, survive outside the iteration (assuming no modifications in between).

Comment: That’s not obvious when neither, `iter1` nor `tmp` are ever passed to a method which could do such a traversal (and add more entries to `tmp`). And more importantly, you don’t iterate over `tmp`. The second step still is an `if` that only processes the first element (of `tmp`).

Comment: I have completely re-written the code to illustrate why a simple loop is not sufficient.

Comment: Sorry, the `if` should have been `while`. Still a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation of `Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html) is very clear about it:

> These instances maintain a connection to the original, backing map. This connection to the backing map is valid *only* for the duration of iteration over the entry-set view. During iteration of the entry-set view, if supported by the backing map, a change to a `Map.Entry`'s value via the [`setValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html#setValue(V)) method will be visible in the backing map. The behavior of such a `Map.Entry` instance is undefined outside of iteration of the map's entry-set view.

An undefined behavior does not preclude doing the intended thing and in practice, when the map is `HashMap` or `TreeMap`, these entry instances keep working as long as you don’t modify the the map (in a different way than calling [`setValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.Entry.html#setValue(V)) on an entry).

The question is whether you want to build your application on such an implementation specific behavior which, while longstanding, has not been specified explicitly.

---

There’s another problem in that you are using these entries as keys in another map. The equality of an entry is determined by the combination of key and value, but not the associated map. In other words, if two entries of different maps happen to have the same key and value, you have a clash and trying to put the other entry will keep the already existing entry but associate it with the new value not meant for this entry (or more precise, not meant for this target map).

Even worse, you are changing the equality while the entry instance is already in use as a key, by calling `setValue` on them, [which is definitely illegal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) and turns the `HashMap` into an inconsistent state:

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects `equals` comparisons while the object is a key in the map.

If all that you are going to do, is to iterate over `tmp` once, there is no need to use a map as no lookup operation is required. A `List<Map.Entry<Key,Value>>` would do instead of `Map<Key,Value>`, to keep a combination of key and value you can iterate over. In fact, any object capable of holding two values could be used instead of `Map.Entry<Key,Value>`. If you replace it with an object capable of holding three values, you could keep track of the target `Map`, key, and new value and just perform a simple `put` at the end.

So the first approach could look like

```java
void recursivePerilousProcedure(Map<String,Object> someMap,
                                List<Map.Entry<Map.Entry<String,Object>,Object>> tmp)
                                throws Exception {
    for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry1: someMap.entrySet()) {
        Object val = entry1.getValue();
        if (val instanceof Map) {
            recursivePerilousProcedure((Map<String,Object>)val, tmp);
        } else {
            Object newval = performPerilousProcedure(val);
            tmp.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry1, newval));
        }
    }
}
void doit(Map<String,Object> someMap) throws Exception {
    List<Map.Entry<Map.Entry<String,Object>,Object>> tmp = new ArrayList<>();

    // Try to process map of entries and record new values
    recursivePerilousProcedure(someMap, tmp);

    // All entries success processed, now simply assign new vals
    // relies on Map implementation detail
    for(Map.Entry<Map.Entry<String,Object>,Object> entry: tmp) {
        Object newval = entry.getValue();
        entry.getKey().setValue(newval); // assign new value
    }
}
```

which is relying on the implementation detail but has the slight advantage that no map lookup is needed when calling `setValue`. Or the clean solution:

```java
record NewValue(Map<String,Object> target, String key, Object newValue) {
    void apply() {
        target.put(key, newValue);
    }
}
void recursivePerilousProcedure(Map<String,Object> someMap,
                                List<NewValue> tmp) throws Exception {
    for(Map.Entry<String,Object> entry1: someMap.entrySet()) {
        Object val = entry1.getValue();
        if (val instanceof Map) {
            recursivePerilousProcedure((Map<String,Object>)val, tmp);
        } else {
            Object newval = performPerilousProcedure(val);
            tmp.add(new NewValue(someMap, entry1.getKey(), newval));
        }
    }
}
void doit(Map<String,Object> someMap) throws Exception {
    List<NewValue> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
    // Try to process map of entries and record new values
    recursivePerilousProcedure(someMap, tmp);

    // All entries success processed, now simply assign new vals
    // assign all new values, cleanly
    tmp.forEach(NewValue::apply);
}
```

Depending on your application, there might be a third option. Just build a new map matching the intended target structure during the recursive processing, to replace the original one when no error occurred.

Comment: Thinking about it, a lot of real life code implicitly relies on validity of entries past iteration. E.g. when you use `map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()) /* more operations */` the sorting starts when the map iteration is over, technically, so all subsequent accesses to the entry also happen after the iteration. Unless we interpret “iteration” generously as “all processing before potentially accessing the map by different means”.

Comment: Great answer. Unfortunately I now have reservations about doing this. The Java 9 `Map.Entry` description seems much more forgiving than Java 17. If `HashMap` (or `TreeMap`) support dereferencing `Map.Entry` outside iteration, I would prefer that `HashMap.entrySet` docs explicitly say so.

Comment: The significant parts are already in [Java 9‘s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html), “*These Map.Entry objects are valid only for the duration of the iteration*”. The new wording looks more strict with the term “outside of iteration”, but as marked in my previous comment, there’s room for interpretation about when the iteration ends. The map doesn’t know about the caller’s loop block. If we are strict and define “when the iterator reports ‘no more elements’ to the caller” as the end, the stream example would already violate the specification.

Comment: The Java 9 full sentence is "These Map.Entry objects are valid only for the duration of the iteration; _more formally, the behavior of a map entry is undefined if the backing map has been modified after the entry was returned by the iterator, except through the setValue operation on the map entry_." which suggests the issue is "more formally" regarding modifying the map.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this multiple times. +1 for citing the specification, +1 for noticing the potential duplicates when using Entry as a map key, +1 for keeping the edits in a List of records instead of in a Map.

Comment: @squarewav The valid lifetime of a Map.Entry is difficult to specify; the "duration of iteration" is a compromise between practical usage and not restricting implementations. It's not possible to determine when the iteration has actually completed -- somebody could break out of a loop early, before hasNext() has returned false. In practice the values returned by getKey and getValue won't change if the Map isn't modified. However, if an HM is modified, getValue can change, but for CHM getValue won't change. The "undefined" behavior is to allow for variations like these.

Comment: Not sure I follow as it seems to me the `Map.Entry`s could be invalidated when `hasNext()` detects the end of the set and returns false.

Comment: @squarewav The history is that Map.Entry intended as a cheap way to iterate a Map without allocating an object per mapping. For HM a Map.Entry is actually an internal node, so it's hard to invalidate, e.g., because overlapping loops return the same instances. (And it would be an incompatible change at this point.) On the flip side the client can break out of the loop prematurely so it never reaches the end. But a returned entry will be invalidated at some ill-defined point in the future, e.g., if the mapping is removed. Also, different Maps have different behaviors.

Comment: @squarewav The "duration of iteration" clause is an attempt to specify a minimum requirement for all Map implementations. For reasons described previously it's difficult to invalidate a Map.Entry, so unfortunately the specification carves out a large region of unspecified behavior (which, as Holger points out, isn't quite correct).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following along, you can do something like this:

```
for (Entry<String, Object> entry : someMap.entrySet()) {
    Object newVal = performPerilousProcedure(entry.getValue());
    tmp.put(entry.getKey(), newVal);
}
    
someMap.putAll(tmp);
```

Comment: Correct for the question initially stated. I have updated the question with an additional condition. Sorry for moving the goal post.